# How do I add a label to an AntDesign chart?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have the following snippet from my React component.

I tried using the following snippet on the AntDesign example playground, and it worked:

`label: { content: ({ label }: any) => { return label } },`

However, no matter what I do, I can't get labels working on my local version of AntDesign.

```js
const config = {
        data: [usageData, limitData],
        xField: 'date',
        yField: ['value'],
        seriesField: 'kind',
        geometryOptions: [
            {
                geometry: 'column',
                isGroup: true,
                seriesField: 'kind',
            },
            {
                geometry: 'line',
                lineStyle: {
                    lineWidth: 2,
                    lineDash: [4, 5],
                },

                label: "example label" // Does not work
                // label: { content: () => "Limit" } // Also does not work

                // label: {
                //     content: ({ label }: any) => label,
                // }, // Also, does not work.
            },
        ],
    };
    return <DualAxes {...config} />;
```

- `"@ant-design/plots": "1.2.5"`

Comment: Can you create a running https://codesandbox.io/ code to reproduce your issue?